# Allow only one record where two lookup fields match another

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

I'm trying to prevent duplicate records from being created.  I have an application object with two relevant fields that looks like this:

Application__c:

- Applicant (Lookup(User))
- School (Lookup(School__c))

I'd like to only allow 1 application per applicant per school.  An applicant can apply only once to each school.  The applicant can apply to many schools.

I'm struggling a bit on where to start.  What's the best way to go about preventing a new record?

I've started looking into Duplicate Rules, but when I try to set matching criteria the two lookup fields are not available, although other custom fields are.
If that's not going to work, I'm guessing I'll have to look at [Apex triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.code_define_trigger.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

**Via configuration**

You can create a text field in application (36 characters) and mark it as unique.

On every save that field is populated by `ApplicantOrUserId+SchoolId` either via a workflow, before trigger or before save flow.

This way only one application can be created per Applicant per School

**Via code**

Create a trigger and calculate the same composite key and use add error when you find a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @manjit,  I'll take a look into those methods.

Comment: I did as @manjit5190 suggested.

I created a flow that updated a unique text field with UserId+SchoolId. 

When entering a duplicate Salesforce gives an error, not a very intelligible one, but It prevents duplicates none the less.